# List the directories whose the file sizes are all within a range

Tags: linux, bash

I want to list the directories containing whose the file sizes are all in within a range.  My solution is to look at each directory and if its all file sizes where in the range, show that in out. I want to know if there exist an easier way to check like a switch in find command or any other command like this.

for example: the range= 10 - 20

```
dir1:
f1 size=12
f2 size= 19

dir2:
f3 size=22
f4 size=11

OUTPUT = dir1
```

dir2 is excluded because f3 is outside the 10-20 range.  dir1 is not excluded, because all its files have sizes inside the range.

Comment: Without commenting on whether it's better to "use `du` and `awk`", you can certainly do this with a pseudo-one-liner involving `find`: `for dir in dir1 dir2; do [[ -z "$(find "$dir" -type f \( -size -10c -o -size +20c \) 2>/dev/null)" ]] && echo "$dir"; done`. (You should get `dir1` as output.)

Comment: do you mean the total size of files in a directory or the size of one file?

Comment: @OznOg I mean the size of each file in a directory

Comment: @4ae1e1: you can speed that up (potentially a lot) with `-print -quit` at the end of that.  So `find` exits after printing the first non-match for a subdir.  Also, nice idea.  I was thinking along those lines, of using find to get non-matching files, but then filtering that output later.  You could do that maybe with `-printf` to print just the cmdline arg that it was found under.

Comment: @PeterCordes Right, that's nicer.

Comment: are there subdirectories in your dir? should they be considered?

Comment: @4ae1e1: I combined our ideas into a shell-function answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing code from [4ae1e1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944784/4ae1e1)'s comment:

Find the first exception to the rule (if any) in each command-line-specified subdirectory.  Print that if it's allowed.

```
dir_filesize_rangefilter() {
    # args: lo hi  paths...
    # sizes in MiB
    # return value: dir names printed to stdout
    local lo=$1 hi=$2
    shift 2  # "$@" is now just the paths

    for dir; do   # in "$@"   is implicit
        local safedir=$dir
        [[ $dir = /* ]] || safedir=./$dir   # make sure find doesn't treat weird -filenames as -options
        # find the first file smaller than lo or larger than hi
        [[ -z "$(find "$safedir" -type f 
               \( -size "-${lo}M" -o -size "+${hi}M" \)
               -print -quit )"
        ]] && printf '%s\n' "$dir"
    done
}
```

I used "printf" because "echo" breaks if one of the directory names starts with `-e` or something.  You could have this add allowed directories to an array, instead of printing them to stdout, if you really want to be paranoid about valid filenames (since you'd have to parse the output of this with an `while IFS= read` loop or something to allow any character, and that still breaks on dir names containing a newline.)

Apparently SO's syntax highlighting doesn't know the quoting rules for quotes inside `$(command substitution)` :/

Comment: Speaking of stupid directory names starting with dash, they would also break `find`... So using `./$dir` if it's not absolute is probably better.

Comment: @4ae1e1: good catch;  fixed.  I couldn't think of a clever `${dir/pattern/replace}` expansion to do it without the two-step temp variable conditional assignment.

Comment: `${dir/#-/./-}`? Anyway, a bit too hackish for my taste. I'm all for verbose yet self-documenting code.

Comment: @4ae1e1: I agree about readability, for sure.  I'm undecided on putting `./` in front of any non-absolute path, vs. only replacing when it actually starts with `-`.  It feels more like the "always quote unless you explicitly *want* unquoted" rule of thumb.  But coming at it the other way is neat idea, if there aren't any other weird characters that can cause a problem.  Took me a while (hence the "always quote" rule of thumb, as I'm sure you know :), but I thought of one: `(` as a filename for find causes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution in 3 lines. I give it in a concrete example:

1. List of all files greater than 1MB into a file:
   `du -hat 1M > gr.dat`
2. List of all files smaller than 3MB into a different file:
   `du -hat -3M > sm.dat`
3. Use grep to find matches in both generated files:
   `grep -F -x -f gr.dat sm.dat`

Comment: That finds directories containing at least one allowed file, not directories containing *only* allowed files.  Like 4ae1e1 suggested in comments, you can generate a list disallowed files, and then print only the directories that didn't contain any of those.